# Is there a way to have type literals in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, dynamic-typing, static-typing

Right now, I'm trying to create a prototype dynamic typing system in C++ for answering another question on Stack Overflow.

But, I'm wondering how I might be able to select a specific type from a variant.

What I want is basically a function to convert a key directly into a type, and then have a program construct a type based on that type literal.

What I want (in pseudo-code):

```
std::string type;

TYPE get_type(std::string) { ... }

get_type(type) new_variable();
```

Comment: Is this any help? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Comment: @Galik I'm not sure, but I'm inclined to say no because I think there's no `eval()` equivalent in C++, so allowing for variable string literal operator means nothing if you cannot dynamically evaluate C++ code at runtime.

Comment: The return (compile-time) *type* cannot depend of the (runtime) value of the std::string.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm just wondering if runtime variant narrowing could be done.

Comment: Continuation passing style acceptable?  Otherwise, no.

Comment: @Yakk what does this mean

Comment: [Continuation passing style](http://goo.gl/JrBm5R) acceptable?  Otherwise, no.

Comment: You keep referring to variants, but the term's normally used to refer to a management object for a discriminated union, such that a single compile time object can effective store any of several types at runtime, and I don't see how that relates to your question or example code.  If you're just saying you want get_type to work for several types, why not use template specialisation to list the mappings?  Very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using continuation passing style, sortof.

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
#define TYPEOF(...) type_t<std::decay_t<decltype(__VA_ARGS__)>>

template<class F>
auto get_type( std::string s, F f ) {
  if (s=="int")
    return f(tag<int>{});
  if (s=="double")
    return f(tag<double>{});
}
```

use:

```
void do_stuff( std::string type ) {
  int x = get_type( type, [&](auto tag) {
    TYPEOF(tag) var;
    return 7;
  });
}
```

in this case, `var` is a variable of the type that `type` names.

Note that all branches will be compiled, so all branches must produce valid code.

Otherwise, no, this isn't possible, barring `constexpr` magic.